# How to generate the 256 bit binary representation of an encoded signature value?

Tags: python, sha256

Sorry for the somewhat vague question, but I am not sure what information I am exactly looking for.

I am using mitmproxy to analyze specific requests sent to the server. These requests have a part named signature that is encoded with base64:

```
"signature":{"value":"SkmsMFNubSonX13bhnR9fOaWQ3c+ObXMDJZXJqV1BuUEBXkYLJCtzsQh2HaGpEEKUjN2wlvVK3YKss2O0ElwYXgv0qAERSKNuiWOCTFQwru9muBNwGhsHU83DXiGHhKGKLhYOT2pG85lc5nN1U4mqN09Wd6ED0pkMius8HPXu39nNavIHE3II3DeKiFCtZKtifiA9ccS4Q4gLmHIviQZHiaGugPtqOkjbTlROvgurZsoIh37lFekfLlEC7C+2YA9yOfE9AY0kBcrZBmrzTN2ypx3lMB6\\/F2lZ2JvZEh7t7gQreYnXUdXGbvq4pM4fHKgdfhgwYtZoiyR77YK3\\/GNGw=="
```

When decoding this, it turns out this is an 256bit file. Which leaves me to think it is some kind of SHA256 encoding of the full request.

However, when I try to emulate this, I only manage to generate 32bit hashes, so I would really love to know how a 256bit file like the one above is generated.

Comment: What are you doing to emulate this? sha256 outputs (as the name suggests) 256 bits. Are you maybe confusing bits and bytes?

Comment: Uhm, yes. The bin file is 256 bytes, not bits

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
import base64

text = "SkmsMFNubSonX13bhnR9fOaWQ3c+ObXMDJZXJqV1BuUEBXkYLJCtzsQh2HaGpEEKUjN2wlvVK3YKss2O0ElwYXgv0qAERSKNuiWOCTFQwru9muBNwGhsHU83DXiGHhKGKLhYOT2pG85lc5nN1U4mqN09Wd6ED0pkMius8HPXu39nNavIHE3II3DeKiFCtZKtifiA9ccS4Q4gLmHIviQZHiaGugPtqOkjbTlROvgurZsoIh37lFekfLlEC7C+2YA9yOfE9AY0kBcrZBmrzTN2ypx3lMB6\\/F2lZ2JvZEh7t7gQreYnXUdXGbvq4pM4fHKgdfhgwYtZoiyR77YK3\\/GNGw=="

decoded = base64.b64decode(text)
print(len(decoded))  # this 256 bytes (not bits)

reencoded = base64.b64encode(decoded)
reencoded_text = reencoded.decode()  # bytes to string
print(reencoded_text == text)  # this is False!  Because of strange `\\` in text

fixed_text = "SkmsMFNubSonX13bhnR9fOaWQ3c+ObXMDJZXJqV1BuUEBXkYLJCtzsQh2HaGpEEKUjN2wlvVK3YKss2O0ElwYXgv0qAERSKNuiWOCTFQwru9muBNwGhsHU83DXiGHhKGKLhYOT2pG85lc5nN1U4mqN09Wd6ED0pkMius8HPXu39nNavIHE3II3DeKiFCtZKtifiA9ccS4Q4gLmHIviQZHiaGugPtqOkjbTlROvgurZsoIh37lFekfLlEC7C+2YA9yOfE9AY0kBcrZBmrzTN2ypx3lMB6/F2lZ2JvZEh7t7gQreYnXUdXGbvq4pM4fHKgdfhgwYtZoiyR77YK3/GNGw=="

print(reencoded_text == fixed_text)  # this is True
```

It's unclear why those backslashes are in your source text to begin with. Apparently, someone thought to escape the foreward slashes that follow, even though I don't know of languages where that would be required.

If you remove the superfluous backslashes, the text still decodes and encodes identically.

```
print(reencoded == base64.b64encode(base64.b64decode(fixed_text)))
```

That's `True` as well, so `reencoded` based on your `text` is the same as the reencoded version of `fixed_text` - the backslashes are not needed.

Note: the `.decode()` on the `reencoded` is needed because `b64encode()` encodes a character string into a base64 encoded string of bytes, i.e. a `bytes`. Since we want to compare it with `text`, which is a character string, we need to use `.decode()` to decode the `bytes` into `str` - the string will still be the base64 representation of the original string.